# How can I implement keypress on a cli with inquirer?

Tags: typescript, command-line-interface, copy-paste, inquirerjs

I created a CLI in typescript using Inquirer but I can't implement a logic to support the command ctrl+v!
I found, on inquirer/core, the method useKeyPress but I don't understand how I can use it in a classic prompt like:

```
const answer = await inquirer.prompt([
{
  type: 'input',
  name: 'question',
  message: 'Insert someting:',
validate: function (value: string) {
  if (!value) {
    return "IYou must insert something.";
  }
  return true;
},
},    
]);
```

Can someone help me?

edit:
Thankfully to @jsejcksn I create this class:
import {
createPrompt,
useState,
useKeypress,
usePrefix,
isEnterKey,
isBackspaceKey,
AsyncPromptConfig,
} from '@inquirer/core';
import type {} from '@inquirer/type';
type InputConfig = AsyncPromptConfig & {
default?: string;
transformer?: (value: string, { isFinal }: { isFinal: boolean }) => string;
};

export default createPrompt<string, InputConfig>((config, done) => {
const [status, setStatus] = useState('pending');
const [defaultValue, setDefaultValue] = useState<string | undefined>(config.default);
const [errorMsg, setError] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);
const [value, setValue] = useState('');

const isLoading = status === 'loading';
const prefix = usePrefix(isLoading);

useKeypress(async (key, rl) => {
// Ignore keypress while our prompt is doing other processing.
if (status !== 'pending') {
return;
}

```
if (isEnterKey(key)) {
  const answer = value || defaultValue || '';
  setStatus('loading');
  const isValid = await config.validate(answer);
  if (isValid === true) {
    setValue(answer);
    setStatus('done');
    done(answer);
  } else {
    // TODO: Can we keep the value after validation failure?
    // `rl.line = value` works but it looses the cursor position.
    setValue('');
    setError(isValid || 'You must provide a valid value');
    setStatus('pending');
  }
} else if (isBackspaceKey(key) && !value) {
  setDefaultValue(undefined);
} else {
  setValue(rl.line);
  setError(undefined);
}
```

});

const message = config.message;
let formattedValue = value;
if (typeof config.transformer === 'function') {
formattedValue = config.transformer(value, { isFinal: status === 'done' });
}

let defaultStr = '';
if (defaultValue && status !== 'done' && !value) {
defaultStr =  `(${defaultValue})`;
}

let error = '';
if (errorMsg) {
error = `> ${errorMsg}`;
}
return [`${prefix} ${message}${defaultStr} ${formattedValue}`, error];
});

but the compiler returns:
error TS2345: Argument of type '{ type: string; name: string; message: string; validate: (value: string) => true | "Il valore non può essere nullo."; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'InputConfig'.
Property 'message' is missing in type '{ type: string; name: string; message: string; validate: (value: string) => true | "IYou must insert something."; }[]' but required in type 'AsyncPromptConfig'.
and also:
error TS2339: Property 'question' does not exist on type 'string'.

where I try to retrieve the answer of the question!

Comment: First-party documentation: https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js/tree/inquirer%409.1.4/packages/core#readme

Comment: Thanks @jsejcksn for your comment, I tried to follow your link but the compiler gave two errors, can you help me to understand where is now the problem?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75370627/how-can-i-implement-keypress-on-a-cli-with-inquirer?noredirect=1#comment133016570_75370627) Not based on the current state of your question — but it would help your question to provide a [mre], ideally with a link to a TypeScript Playground which includes the same example demonstrating the problem. Here's a playground link to get started — I've preconfigured it to use Node + `inquirer`: https://tsplay.dev/N75g4W

Comment: This example, I think, reproduce a very similar error: can it help as starting point? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true

Comment: Sorry @jsejcksn I'm totally blind so I don't find the comment tou're refferring, anyway here it is the link to playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75370627/how-can-i-implement-keypress-on-a-cli-with-inquirer?noredirect=1#comment133037189_75370627) The links that you've shared don't contain any code.

Comment: grrr why if I open the same link I can see the code? Should I "save" in some manner?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75370627/how-can-i-implement-keypress-on-a-cli-with-inquirer?noredirect=1#comment133041881_75370627) The "Share" button above the code will copy the URL to your clipboard.